Full Calendar TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'timeZoneOffset') - using RRule exdate
I'm using Full Calendar and rrule plug in .net 8 core project. I'm trying to add the exdate to recurring events. Here is my code
events: function (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("GetCalendarEvents", "CalendarEvents")",
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        var events = [];

        $.each(response, function () {
            var e = "'2024-11-05T13:30:00','2024-11-07T13:30:00'";
            var temp = '';
            if (this.dtstart !== null) {
                temp = this.dtstart.replace(/-/g, '');
                temp = temp.replace(/:/g, '');
                var r = 'DTSTART:' + temp + '\nRRULE:' + this.rrule;
            }
            events.push({
                title: this.title,
                start: this.event_start,
                end: this.event_end,
                backgroundColor: this.color,
                borderColor: this.color,
                textColor: '#ffffff',
                rrule: r,
                extendedProps: {
                    description: this.description,
                    start: this.start,
                    end: this.end,
                    color: this.color,
                    start_time: this.start_time,
                    end_time: this.end_time,
                    recurring: this.recurring,
                    id: this.id
                }
                //exdate: [e]
                //exdate: ['2024-11-05T13:30:00', '2024-11-07T13:30:00']
            });
        });
        successCallback(events);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error: ' + textStatus);
        //failureCallback();
    }
});
}

If I pass exdate: ['2024-11-05T13:30:00', '2024-11-07T13:30:00'], all works well. but if I pass exdate as a variable like this
var e = "'2024-11-05T13:30:00','2024-11-07T13:30:00'";
exdate: [e]

I get TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'timeZoneOffset') error. Any idea what mistake I'm making?
The reason I'm using variable is because the exdates will come from an ajax call to database.

I believe the issue occurs because exdate needs to be an array of date strings without the additional quotes you put around them. var e has double quotes around the variable and single quotes around each date. Is it possible for you to create variable like this: var e = ['2024-11-05T13:30:00', '2024-11-07T13:30:00']; ? Maybe you can create 1 array of multiple dates and join them together in one string?

You're welcome. I will write this as an answer,  can you please mark it as correct because it worked for you

I believe the issue occurs because exdate needs to be an array of date strings without the additional quotes you put around them. Var e has double quotes around the variable and single quotes around each date. Is it possible for you to create variable like this: var e = ['2024-11-05T13:30:00', '2024-11-07T13:30:00']; ?

In database I've exdates stored as '2024-11-05T13:30:00', '2024-11-07T13:30:00'. But not sure how to make this string into array.

let exdatesArray = exdatesString
.split(",")                       // Split the string by commas
.map(date => date.trim())          // Trim whitespace around each date
.map(date => date.replace(/'/g, ''));

@joegreen In database I've exdates stored as '2024-11-05T13:30:00', '2024-11-07T13:30:00'....if you stored it in the database as a JSON string representing an array, this job would be a lot easier. e.g. store it as ["2024-11-05T13:30:00", "2024-11-07T13:30:00"]. If you store data in recognised, machine-readable formats (which have ready-made libraries for working with them) you don't then have to mess about writing code to parse it out from the stored format again. JSON is writeable and readable by just about every programming language on the planet.

After trying different things for one and half day, I finally got it working. I'm posting this here so it saves someone sometime. In my database, the exdates are stored in a table having nvarchar(MAX) column like this  2024-11-05T13:30:00,2024-11-07T13:30:00. No single/double quotes or brackets. Then ajax call returns data.
let g = new Array();
if (this.exdate != null) {      
    var c = this.exdate.split(',');                                    
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        g.push(c[i]);
    }       
}

events.push({
title: this.title,
start: this.event_start,
end: this.event_end,
rrule: r,
extendedProps: {
    description: this.description,
    recurring: this.recurring,
    id: this.id
},
exdate: g 
});

